# How to call a Zend lucene search function?

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene, zend-search-lucene

I inherited a Zend project devoid of comments and I didn't get to talk to the previous developer. Since I have no Zend experience I'm having some issues :)

I'd like to print out some variables inside an function that indexes items from the site using Zend_Search_Lucene because I think something is going wrong here.

From what I've read, ::create creates a new index and ::open updates it. So it's in this ::open function I'd like to print out some variables.

The name and params of the function are below. Does anyone have any idea how this function can be called so I can run some tests?

```
private function search($category,$string,$page = 1,$itemsByPage = 5)
```

EDIT: OR, is there a way I can nuke the existing index and force it to be rebuilt completely, for example by deleting the index files on the FS and then performing some searches?

Comment: ::create deletes an index if it exists

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to create an index from scratch:

```
Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(new StandardAnalyzer_Analyzer_Standard_English());

$tmpIndexDir = '/your/index/dir/'
$index = Zend_Search_Lucene::create($tmpIndexDir);

foreach($myObjects as $myObject){

    $doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();
    $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnIndexed('objectId', $myObject->getId()));
    $contents = $myObject->toString();
    $contentsField = Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('contents', $contents);
    $doc->addField($contentsField);
    $index->addDocument($doc);
}

$index->optimize();
```

... don't remember where i got the standard analyzer from...

Answer (score 0):

good examples - `ZendFramework-1.9.6/demos/Zend/Search/Lucene`

[ZF full distro](http://framework.zend.com/releases/ZendFramework-1.9.6/ZendFramework-1.9.6.zip)